# Server Side Directives File Retrieval Possible in IBM HTTP Server V8.0?

Tags: ssi, penetration-testing, ibmhttpserver

By default, in IBM HTTP Server V8.0 , is server side directives file retrieval possible?

```
e.g. <!--#include file="C:\boot.ini"-->
```

Comment: @BalusC I am using IBM HTTP Server V8.0

Answer (score 0):

In the default configuration, mod_include is loaded but the "Includes" option is not enabled for any context.  Also, #include file= cannot use absolute paths or ../.

Also, this seems like a "try it and see" kind of question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is not "try it and see" question. This is one of the high finding from penetration testing. I need solid justification to prove that this finding is false positive. Thanks.

Comment: What is stronger proof, demonstration of the response or asking the internet what the response might be?